# How to set IP address automatically in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, arch-linux, ip-address

I am using latest Arch Linux. But whenever I start my PC, it sometimes gets an IP address but most of the time, it gives me stress. I am getting very confused, how can I make sure it is really setting DHCP IP?

This is what I have:

In `rc.conf`:

```
DAEMONS=( ... network dhcpcd )
```

On system boot I have in `~/.xinitrc`

```
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip link set dev eht1 up
dhcpcd -t 100
```

But now, I have rebooted 10 times, and I do not get any IP address.

Yesterday, I had interfaces eth0, eth1, lo. After this strange problem of IP, now I am successfully boot back to my same box with the same configuration.

1. I do not have any eth1 any more
2. Network cable was connected to eth1 (eth0 was not used because it's in a very messy place where I have lots of USB and display cables connected)

Why has my eth1 completely disappeared? I never saw this in CentOS or Fedora in my year of Linux driving experience.

Comment: Why are you trying to bring two NIC's up (eth0 and eth1)?

Comment: @jasonwryan: because, if i connect internet cable, to eth0 or eht1, it take wrong interface such as eth0 connected but was before showing eth1. To be sure at-least i am on the network i used that (And it was working yesterday). I have my GRUB timeout=0, and i cant login anymore because i have a full screen slide shows). How do i go back to my grub menu for single boot login? So that i can share you the rc.conf.

Comment: You can only bring one NIC up - the primary one. Follow sr_'s advice and go through the page on the wiki and follow it exactly. Your login issue is a separate one. I don't understand why a slideshow prevents you acessing your console Ctrl-Alt-F{1-6}...

Comment: After BIOS i pressed Ctrl+Alt+F{1 till 6} But i do not get GRUB menu. (i have GRUB timeout=0 and autologin and full screen slideshow after autologin, as a result i do not get anymore my terminal either).

Comment: (I misclicked `^` when I wanted to add a comment)  @jasonwryan meant Ctrl+Alt+F1 after the system booted (into whatever you mean by slideshow), to access a plain text console.

Comment: well... it's not really true that you can only bring one nic up... but bringing more online will be harder... you might want to consider using network manager instead of rc.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some notes on your question, maybe it helps, hopefully:

1. `~/.xinitrc` is not the right place for these settings, [see for example here, in the "ArchWiki"](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinitrc)
2. Don't fight your distribution, ArchLinux's system startup is configured via [`/etc/rc.conf`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Rc.conf), which is pretty neat. This includes the network configuration, [see again the ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_Network) for details, especially the part on [DHCP IP](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Configuring_Network#For_DHCP_IP).  Try to setup networking in the way it is described there and if this fails, it'd be good to have more information on the failure (logs, details about how it was configured).  As you can see, the ArchWiki is a valuable resource `:)`

By the way, the `eht1` is just a typo, right?

Oh, another reason for using the distribution-specific way to configure networking, you can simply use `/etc/rc.d/network restart` to reconfigure (as root), so there should be no need to reboot.

Comment: You could use a live-cd (or live-system on a bootable USB drive, maybe even your install medium's rescue system) to access grub's config file, edit the timeout value, go on from there.

Comment: please see my follow up section. Why i do not have anymore eth1?